# How to append data to txt in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, overwrite, file-writing

I'm writing a program, which needs to take some JSON from text file, then modify it and put it back to the same file, something like overwriting. I don't have problem with reading from file and modifying data, but I was searching long and found nothing about writing into files. If it's important - it's server-side file.

Ex. text file: `{"name":"John","age":20}`
Result which I need: `{"name":"John","age":21}`

Comment: which server-side language/environment are you using ? What's the problem about writing files ??? Please explain what's your issue

Comment: *I was searching long and found nothing about writing into files* Highly unlikely. What did you search?

Comment: Post the code you're using to read the file. That will help us figure out how you might be able to write a file.

Comment: I do not see a very strong reason as to why this has to be written in javascript. However, is there a reason to do so? Nothing wrong in doing, just asking! Things as simple as Powershell will work this case.

Comment: @Pierre I'm using javascript and optionally jquery. The problem is I don't really have an idea how to do it

Comment: You can't do it from the client side, this is something you do on the server

Comment: You need either: a server-side programming language such as Ruby or Javascript (node) or Python or C# or C++ and modify that file on the server **or** your web hosting provider need to provide a HTTP API to upload files. If you have neither of these than what you're trying to do is impossible because browsers can only talk HTTP (or HTTP based protocols like WebSockets)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fs` module in node to write to a file!

information is located here on it https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

The two methods you will want to look at is `.writeFile` or `.appendFile` depending on your specific need.

Comment: I'm using 000webhost where I uploaded my site and using node.js is impossible in my plan

Comment: if you're using php, you can use the methods fwrite(), you can find more information here, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp